# Confusion about order of constructor call and virtual base class

Tags: c++, c++11

**order-of-call.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A" ;
    }

};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "B" ;
    }
};

class C: virtual public A
{
public:
    C()
    {
        std::cout << "C" ;
    }

};

class D: public B, public C
{
public:
    D()
    {
        std::cout << "D" ;        
    }

};


int main()
{
    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
g++ order-of-call.cpp -std=c++11
```

**Output**

```
AABCD
```

Why are the two `A`s together in output?. I was expecting something like `ABACD`. But if I change inheritance order like this
`class D: public C, public B`, the output is as expected `ACABD`. Is the order part of standard or is something specific to g++.

Comment: Hint: What does initializing `B` mean?

Answer (score 6):

This makes sense, as virtual base class is constructed before non-virtual base classes. So in your case it is: `virtual A`, `non-virtual A`, `BCD`. If you change the inheritance order it is `virtual A`, `C`, `non-virtual A`, `BD`. Checkout this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr389.htm

The order of initializing class is following:

> 1. Constructors of Virtual base classes are executed, in the order that they appear in the base list.
> 2. Constructors of nonvirtual base classes are executed, in the declaration order.
> 3. Constructors of class members are executed in the declaration order (regardless of their order in the initialization list).
> 4. The body of the constructor is executed.

Answer (score 4):

This seems highly relevant: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-vi-ctor-order, in particular:

> The very first constructors to be executed are the virtual base classes anywhere in the hierarchy.
>
> After all virtual base class constructors are finished, the construction order is generally from base class to derived class. So if class D inherits multiply from B1 and B2, the constructor for B1 executes first, then the constructor for B2, then the constructor for D.
>
> Note that the order B1 and then B2 (or B1a then B1b) is determined by the order that the base classes appear in the declaration of the class.

So the first `A` you see is always through the virtual inheritance of `C->A`. Rest is usual in-depth-left-to-right.

Answer (score 2):

The construction sequence is virtual bases first, and then construction of non-virtual bases in in-depth left-to-right order (recursively).

So, when constructing a `D`, the virtual base `A` of class `C` will be constructed first (hence the first `'A'` is output).  Then construction of the `B` within `D` begins, which first constructs the non-virtual `A` (outputting the second `'A'`) that is a non-virtual base of `B` and then calls the constructor of `B` (outputting `'B'`).  The constructor of `C` is then called - its base `A` is virtual so is not constructed again, and then the constructor of `C` is called (outputting `'C'`).    Lastly the constructor of `'D'` is invoked (outputting `'D'`).

Answer (score -1):

If you add missing virtual here:

```
class B: virtual public A
```

This will resolve the multiple inheritance problem and you will get one A instance per class

Then output is going to be simple ABCD or in case of changing the order

```
class D: public C, public B
```

Output:

```
ACBD
```

It is in accordance to the standard and this behavior is independent on a compiler you use

However, if you do need to have it is virtual only for C class. The virtual contractor is going to be called first in any case, again accordingly to the standard:

**ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N
3690**

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
> following order:
>
> - First, and only for the constructor of the most
>   derived class (1.8), **virtual base classes** are initialized in the order
>   they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed
>   acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of
>   appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list .
> - Then, direct base classes are initialized in
>   declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>   (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers ).
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the
>   class definition (again regardless of the order of the
>   mem-initializers ).
> - Finally, the compound-statement of the
>   constructor body is executed.

Comment: The OP isn't trying to resolve a multiple inheritance problem. They are asking about the initialization order

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller, I've expanded my answer accordingly. Just want to emphasize that this mix can be used only for study and not for production code

Comment: @IgorPchelnikov - The point you're trying to make is incorrect.  Although it is not usual in practice, "this mix" can be and is used effectively in production code.